# Como pegar o "name" em um editor HTML?

Tags: php, html

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, como vou enviar pelo método POST, o que for digitado dentro de um editor html?

[image: É um sistema de notícia em PHP que eu estou criando]

Eu preciso enviar as informações digitar para o banco de dados, porém não sei como pegar a informação do editor HTML. Segue o código:

```
  <div class="alinha">
    <h3>Sistema de notícias</h3>
    <form action="valida_noticia.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Título da notícia</label>
      <input type="text" name="titulonoticia" class="form-control" placeholder="Forneça o título da notícia">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
      <textarea name="editor"></textarea>
      <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
      </script>
<!--       <div class="adjoined-bottom">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <textarea id='editor' name='editor'></textarea>
        </div>
      </div> -->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Qual editor está utilizando e qual o código JavaScript que cria ele na página?

Comment: Isso tá parecendo CKEditor, mas acho que tá faltando um `<textarea>` aí.

Comment: É um CKEditor em um DIV ? mas mesmo se por em um textarea o CKEditor precisa ser instanciado e pegar o valor da instancia, só o metodo post não pega o valor

Comment: é o CKEDITOR, vou te confessar que sou bem leigo nessa questão de editores HTML, peguei o editor de um exemplo deles e coloquei na página que ia inserir notícias

Comment: @PedroRibeiro você vai enviar o form via ajax ou submeter pela tag <form> mesmo ?

Comment: To enviando via POST, eu vi varios videos no youtube, onde as pessoas colocavam um código em PHP para instanciar o CKEDITOR, porém eu revirei a documentação do CKEDITOR que eu baixei ( Versão 4.6.2 ) e não achei nada de como instanciar o mesmo em PHP. O vídeo que estou usando para me guiar é esse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KhJN-lxRqc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Você não pode colocar um editor em uma `div` se pretende submeter via `form`, deve colocar em um `textarea`:

```
<textarea id='editor' name='editor'></textarea>
```

2 - Para deixar instancia recuperável, você precisa iniciar ela :

```
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );</script>
```

Assim feito, basta utilizar o campo como outro qualquer.

Caso queira utilizar AJAX para submeter o formulário deves recuperar da segunte forma:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
```

Referencia:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <div class="alinha">
    <h3>Sistema de notícias</h3>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="valida_noticia.php" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Título da notícia</label>
           <input type="text" name="titulonoticia" class="form-control" placeholder="Forneça o título da notícia">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <textarea name="editor"></textarea>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" onclick="updateTexto()" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
      </form>
<script>
   function updateTexto()
   {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[editor].updateElement();
        }
    }

   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
</script>
```

[CKEditor Docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/)

Comment: o editor não aparece, fiz como vc falou. Só aparece um text area normal de html

Comment: @PedroRibeiro Da uma olhada no código adicionado agora no final ali

Comment: Eu coloco isso tudo no lugar daquela div?

Comment: @PedroRibeiro pode colocar em qualquer lugar, a unica coisa que precisa é o 'id' do textarea ser o mesmo do valor de CKEDITOR.replace('aqui tem que ser igual'), e também de ter importado a biblioteca no inicio da pagina.

Comment: Agora tá aparacendo o editor, porém a variavél tá indo vazia pelo metodo post: string(0) "" NULL

Comment: Ok, proximo passo, você envia esse formulário por um botão submit dentro de <form> ou de algum outro jeito ?

Comment: botao submit dentro do form, vou editar meu codigo para você ver como esta

Comment: @PedroRibeiro da uma olhada na edição, dei uma corrigida no seu HTML, e adicionei a função que preenche o valor, mas é uma função meio antiga, veja se assim funciona agora.

Comment: Não funcionou :(. string(0) "" NULL

Comment: @PedroRibeiro faz muito tempo que não uso isso, testa se desse modo da certo agr, adicionei enctype no form, e o nome da instancia, assim que der eu explico o porque na resposta.

Comment: Você nao editou a resposta

Comment: @PedroRibeiro editei sim, foi só duas mudancinhas, veja na tag <form> e na funcao javascript

Comment: string(0) "" NULL

Comment: Coloca isso no arquivo php que recebe: var_dump(htmlentities($_POST['editor']));

Comment: Ue, desse jeito aparece: string(29) "<p>TESTANDO</p> "

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67700/discussion-between-anthraxisbr-and-pedro-ribeiro).

Answer (score 0):

Complementando o que o amigo @AntharixBR falou, você deve utilizar um textarea para usar o CKEditor e utilizar a instância para ele funcionar. Já para recuperar os dados do textarea para enviar o formulário, os métodos são:

PHP

```
$nomedavariavel = $_POST['nomedatextarea'];
```

JS

```
var nomedavar = $('textarea[name=noemdatextarea]').val();
```

Qualquer duvida só chamar amigo!